# C# Removing control from one Grid and adding it to another

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I've got a heavy control from Telerik - RadRichTextBox and it takes ages while loading. I created it on application start and I am adding and removing it to/from Grid in different places.

```
if (gridG.Children.Contains(textEditControl))
   gridG.Children.Remove(textEditControl);
```

and

```
if (!gridG.Children.Contains(textEditControl))
   gridG.Children.Add(textEditControl);
```

I also backup it's content before removing and restore after adding when it's necessary.

Grid is inside popup.

**The problem is** I got error. It happens after opening popup, switching few times RRTB between Grids, closing it and opening once more - then I got this error:

```
at Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.LayoutElement.SetParent(LayoutElement newParent)
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.Layout.LayoutBox.get_Parent()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.DocumentPosition.GetCurrentTableCellBox()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.DocumentPosition.GetCurrentTableRowBox()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.DocumentPosition.GetCurrentTableBox()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.TableStylesGallery.TrySetSelectedTableStyle()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.TableStylesGallery.CaretPosition_PositionChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.DocumentPosition.OnPositionChanged()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.Utils.SuspendChangingAndChangedActionCounter.InvokeChangedActionInternal()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.Utils.SuspendChangingAndChangedActionCounter.InvokeChanged()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.DocumentPosition.CallOnPositionChanged(Boolean changesCursorInitialLocation)
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.DocumentPosition.Reset()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.Model.RadDocument.Measure(SizeF measureSize)
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.UI.DocumentWebLayoutPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at MS.Internal.Helper.MeasureElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
   at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()
   at Telerik.Windows.Documents.UI.DocumentPresenterBase.Telerik.Windows.Controls.IDocumentEditorPresenter.UpdateLayout()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadRichTextBox.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<UpdateEditorLayout>b__1d()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadRichTextBox.UpdateEditorLayout(Boolean focusCarret, Boolean updateCaretSize, Boolean async)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadRichTextBox.UpdateEditorLayout(Boolean async)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RadRichTextBox.UpdateEditorLayout()
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.Dialogs.Styles.ObservableStyleCollection..ctor(RadDocument document, RadRichTextBox snapshotRichtextBox, Int32 snapshotWidth, Int32 snapshotHeight, Boolean addClearAllStyle, Boolean onlyPrimary)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.StylesGallery.SetInitialQuickStyleItemSource(RadRichTextBox radRichTextBox)
   at Telerik.Windows.Controls.RichTextBoxUI.StylesGallery.<>c__DisplayClass1.<SetQuickStyleItemSource>b__0()
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

I tried to put everything in try/catch block but it didn't work. Perhaps some exception is thrown inside Telerik's library.

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Which version of Telerik are you using -- Winforms, Silverlight, ASP.NET...?

Comment: Cool, add the WPF tag to your question then. That should help get your question more views by allowing people who follow WPF to see it too.